# Seeking CityGML Viewer for big data?

Tags: software-recommendations, citygml

Could you suggest a solution to view CityGML data which is about 1.36GB?

I tried in fzk viewer and fme data inspector, it is very slow.

Answer (score 3):

for such big files you need to use a database if you want to visualise your data because it is too big to be directly loaded in computer memory. I advice you to use 3dcitydb (https://www.3dcitydb.org/) to store your CitGML data in PostGRES.

A viewer is also provided with this tool (https://www.3dcitydb.org/3dcitydb/d3dwebclient/).

I didn't test it, but, when I need to visualise big CityGML files, I do it with Geoserver (http://geoserver.org/) that can stream your data to a 3D client application such as CesiumJS (https://cesiumjs.org/). But it requiers some code to work.